# Can you plan to found a company?

Tags: word-usage, tenses

I know that you can use the word "found" in the past tense. For example:

> He founded Google in 1998.

Say I plan to create/start up a new company in the future. Could I say:

> I plan to found a tech company.

I know there are alternative ways to say this, but can I use the word "found" in this situation?

Comment: It sounds like a conflict of registers (but then so does 'found' with many modern things).

Comment: Thousands of people have planned to found a company.  Very few have done so.

Comment: If _found_ is regular (which the past tense _founded_ suggests), then it will have an infinitive form _found_, which will be grammatical after the _to_ complementizer. The verb _plan_ can take practically any infinitive clause with Equi-Subject like this (i.e, same subject of _plan_ and _found_), provided the verb is one that can have a human subject.

Comment: This reminds me a little of a question we had 3 years ago from a 12-year-old who stated her intention to write a "classic novel"...who are we to stomp on their dreams?

Comment: That is correct, but is sounds a bit unnatural. Here's an example from the OED: *Bismarck is eager to found colonies in all parts of the world.* And another from the Corpus of Contemporary American English: *They're intrigued too by her hint of a plan to found a think tank where scientists and political analysts will create policy aimed at placing Planned Parenthood right in the middle of the nation's "family values" debates.*

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use 'found' in that situation, just as you can use 'start', 'establish', 'begin', etc.

found verb (BEGIN)

B2 [ T ]

to bring something into existence:

[Found (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/found)

> *they planned to found a school of their own*
>
> *Francis planned to found Fizwizz, an online retail recruitment agency*
>
> *In 1147, Robert de Beaumont, 2nd Earl of Leicester planned to found a convent*
>
> *They moved to Athens in 1871 where Syngros planned to found a new
> bank.*
>
> *He [Henry VIII] planned to found a college of canons governed by a
> dean*